# Select features of layer which is not on top in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wfs

I have posted this question before on the general StackOverflow forum:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16278569/select-features-of-layer-which-is-not-on-top

In short my problem is that I have a baselayer, an overlay layer and a WFS layer in OL.
The base and overlay layers are WMS using GWC in GeoServer.
I want to select a feature of the WFS layer but KEEP the overlay layer on top.

By binding a selectFeature control to the WFS layer moves the layer on top.
Using

```
map.setLayerZIndex(overlayLayer, map.Z_INDEX_BASE["Feature"]+10);
```

I move the overlay layer back.
But now I can no longer select a feature of the WFS layer.

Adding the overlayLayer to the SelectFeature control doesn't work because it is a WMS layer.

How can I select a feature on the WFS layer which is not on top?
I've tried the GetFeature control, but that requires a roundtrip to the server and I don't want.

I've made an sample of my problem at http://www.smartdakscan.nl/webapps/assen/selectFeature.html

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused. You want to select something on the WMS layer (which is just an image), but you don't want to do a round-trip to the server to get a new image with the item selected when you select something?

Comment: Do you want to just display information about the feature or do you also want to show it highlighted?

Comment: I want the WMS layer on top. It is just a non-solid polygon with a house number (grouped layer from GeoServer). But I want to select a feature on the WFS layer. I want to highlight the feature and show its information.

The selection is working OK if the WFS layer is on top, but I want the WMS layer to be on top.

Comment: why do you want the WMS on top? being a non-solid polygon it should be visible also beneath the WFS layer (using it as a transparent image)

Comment: @Gery: You are right. But my non-solid WMS also has a label which falls beneath my solid WFS.

Comment: Well, for this I'd say that you can separate labels from the wfs layer, based in [this](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18195/how-to-add-labels-to-a-wms-layer-using-openlayers-and-geoserver) that's possible, take a look at it and see if it works for you

Comment: Thanks Gery for your suggestions.
I can split the labels from the WMS layer but that doesn't make a difference because the WFS layer is still rendered on top and thus the labels are beneath it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `setLayerIndex` instead `setLayerZIndex` which is a "private" method.
Using the `setLayerZIndex` you simple change the z-index of the DOM elements but not the position of the layer within the map's layer stack.

Once you have ordered the layers as you want, you are right using the `SelectFeature` control passing the desired layer (WFS) where to select features.

Cheers.